# Mangalagiri Panakala (Panagam) Narasimha's miracle

Tags: puranas, narasimha

A small town near Vijayawada named Mangalagiri. On the top of the hill Lord Narasimha in sitting posture blesses all. His mouth is wide open. Panakam(Panagam) is made of jaggery mixed with water with dried ginger, elaichi and will be in liquid form. If one jug full  of Panakam (Panagam) is given to the archaka and he pours in Narasimha's mouth exactly half of the Panakam (Panagam) will be consumed by Lion god and the rest he will give as Prasad to devotees. Not even a single drop will go more than that half jug. Any evidence from puranas for this miracle. I went once and experienced this amidst a good darshan.